# Как проверить есть ли пользователь в sql таблице?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite3

Пока что код проверки выглядит так:

```
info_user_to = cursor.execute(""" SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE name IN '%s'""" % (user_to))

If info_user_to:
   print('Это имя уже занято.')
else:
   print('Ок.')
```

Каждый раз программа выдаёт ошибку:
no such table: <Имя пользователя, который я ввёл>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE name='%s'
```

Если только одно условие, то используй формулировку выше

Оператор IN - это сокращение для нескольких OR или когда нужно несколько WHERE

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь

Answer (score 0):

1. =, а не IN, как уже сказано
2. Подстановка через ?, чтобы защититься от всяких SQL INJECTIONS, да и вообще удобнее, когда будет больше параметров
3. Проверяем, что `rowcount` не ноль, а объект результата (это, собственно, сам курсор) возвращается всегда и он всегда `True`

`cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE name=?", [user_to])`

`if cursor.rowcount:`

Answer (score 0):

```
info_user_to = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE name = " + 
str(user_to)).fetchall()

If len(info_user_to) > 0:
   print('Это имя уже занято.')
else:
   print('Ок.')
```

Comment: здесь может быть SQL инъекция